# Distribute $a$ distinguishable balls into $b$ distinguishable boxes

Tags: combinatorics

I was given the next question: What is the number of the options to distribute $a$ distinguishable balls into $b$ distinguishable boxes leaving exactly $c$ boxes empty
whereas $a,b,c$ are all natural numbers which equal to/bigger than $1.$
and $a$ => $b$ - $c$

I'd really like some hints/clues..I find it quite confusing, handling problems with distinguishable/un-distinguishable balls and boxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First pick the empty boxes-how many ways to do that?  Then each ball has $b-c$ places to go.  Then you have to subtract the ways that leave another box empty, which will require inclusion/exclusion.  Subtract the ways with $c-1$ boxes empty, but you have subtracted the ones with $c-2$ empty too may times, so add them back in, and so on.

Comment: @rogerl:  You are right-brain glitch.  Added.

Comment: How do I find the possible options for placing the distinct balls into the b-c distinct boxes?

Comment: As I said, each ball has $b-c$ places to go, and you make that choice $a$ times, so there are $(b-c)^a$ ways to place them.  The problem comes in that you might leave some other boxes empty.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question..but I don;t understand why it's (b−c)^a?
Why their factorial product isn't the right answer?

Comment: Having chosen $c$ bins to be empty, there are $b-c$ you can fill.  Take the first ball.  You have $b-c$ places to put it.  Now take the second.  You again have $b-c$ places to put it.  As the balls are distinguishable, putting the first in bin 1 and the second in bin 2 is different from the first in bin 2 and the second in bin 1, so the total number of ways to place them is $(b-c)^2$.  The choices are completely intdependent, so you multiply.

Comment: Thank you so so much! I got confused for a moment

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the empty boxes in ${b \choose c}$ ways. To place the $a$ balls into the $b-c$ non-emtpy labelled boxes, you have $ (b-c)! S_{a,b-c} $ ways, where $S_{i,j}$ is the [Stirling number of the second kind.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) Hence the answer is

$$ {b \choose c}  (b-c)! S_{a,b-c} $$